# Determining Sum while excluding certain values

Tags: python, excel, pandas, sum

I need some help with a vert quick calculation, in the denominator line below I need to get the sum of the string occurances, yet only need to sum over values which are above a value, so for example, I need to get the sum of all of them, but exclude the number that comes with a certain occurance at 2, so theoretically I need something along the lines of:

```
enominator = np.sum(occurances yet only sum above the value of occurances(2))



            # the next bit uses the True/False columns to find the ranges in which a 
            # series of avalanches happen.
            fst = bins.index[bins['avalanche'] & ~ bins['avalanche'].shift(1).fillna(False)]
            lst = bins.index[bins['avalanche'] & ~ bins['avalanche'].shift(-1).fillna(False)]
            for i, j in zip(fst, lst):
                bins.loc[j, 'total count'] = sum(bins.loc[i:j+1, 'count'])
                bins.loc[j, 'total duration'] = (j-i+1)*bin_width

            writer = pd.ExcelWriter(bin_file)
            bins.to_excel(writer)
            writer.save()

            # When a series of avalanches occur, we need to add them up. 
            occurances = bins.groupby(bins['total count']).size()

            # Fill in the gaps with zero
            occurances = occurances.reindex(np.arange(occurances.index.min(), occurances.index.max()), fill_value=0)
            # Create a new series that shows the percentage of outcomes
            denominator = np.sum(occurances)
            print(denominator)
            percentage = occurances/denominator
            #print (denomimator)
```

So, this takes an excel file and runs it as a dataframe, nonetheless, I'm having trouble, like I mentioned earlier, calculating the variable denominator. Occurances simply adds up the number of times a given values is present, however, i need to calculate denominator such that:

denominator = np.sum(occurances) - occurances[2] + occurances[1]

Yet if it occurances[2] or occurances[1] isn't present it crashes, so how would I go about taking the sum of occurances[3] and above, I also tried:
denominator = np.sum(occurances) >=occurances[3]
but it only gave me a True and False statement and would crash shortly after. So I basically need the sum of the values present in occurances[3] and above. Thank you any help is appreciated

Comment: You should look to provide a [MCVE], i.e. simplify the code above to just your issue so it is easier for someone to provide help. A masked sum is probably what you need, see [`numpy.ma.sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.sum.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using a conditional index:

```
denominator = occurances[occurances > occurances(2)].sum()
```

Comment: I tried that, but I get the the error:                                                                             TypeError: 'Series' object not callable

Comment: What error? I'm assuming `occurances(2)` is not valid syntax but this was just copied from your pseudocode - did you mean `occurances[2]`?

Comment: Thanks brother it works, but now I get another error which is kind of annoying though:                                                                                      File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 339, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:7415)
KeyError: 3.0

Comment: Again I suggest you edit your original question, make a [MCVE] providing details like what data is in `occurances` and expected output.